# Install Comodo SSL Cert for AWS Elastic Beanstalk Instance

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, elastic-beanstalk

I purchased a wildcard SSL cert from Comodo SSL, but am really confused on how to install it to use with my AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance.

The files they sent me are:

- STAR_setheroapp_com.crt
- STAR_setheroapp_com.ca-bundle
- Wildcard Cert in txt format

Any help is gladly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

The certificate issued by the Certificate Authority should be uploaded to IAM along with the private key and certificate chain (CA Bundle). After uploading, the certificates are available for other AWS services to use.

The tool for certificate uploading is AWS command line interface (CLI).

*note: the Certificate Authority can send you the certificate in a format that is not supported by IAM. The correct format is x.509 PEM. The files with .crt extension are in PEM format, so in order to use them for certificate uploading, you can simply rename the .crt file to .pem file.
Otherwise, the certificate should be converted to the correct format using OpenSSL. The specific command depends on the current format of your certificate.

You will need three files for uploading:

1. Your certificate in PEM format
2. Private key in PEM format
3. Certificate chain

If you received it as separate files (e.g. `COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt`, `COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt` and `AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt`), you can either combine them in one file using OpenSSL command or download the Bundle as one file here.
The OpenSSL command to combine separate certificates into one full CA Bundle is:

```
cat intermediate1.crt intermediate2.crt root.crt > ssl-bundle.crt
```

In our example the command will look this way:

```
cat COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > ssl-bundle.crt
```

You can upload all three files from the command line with one command:

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name certificate_object_name --certificate-body file://certificate --private-key file://privatekey.pem --certificate-chain file://certificate_chain_file
```

Otherwise: Get Comodo Certificate Manager for Comodo Quick & Easy SSL Installation (Online Support)